# Irrational packing of Euclidean spaces (with no gaps).

Tags: geometry, number-theory, euclidean-geometry, irrational-numbers, packing-problem

This appears to be a new question on MSE. [The only post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37776/104041) on here after a search using the string `irrational "packing"` does not mention (explicitly) what I have in mind. [A Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-zte&ei=yT9MXP6DII2D1fAPuL2p6Ac&q=+"packing"+with+irrational+number+length+cubes&oq=+"packing"+with+irrational+number+length+cubes&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3...36165.54537..55033...0.0..0.325.4898.11j26j1j1......0....1.........0i71j0i131i67j0i67j0j0i22i30j33i22i29i30j33i160j33i21.1t8eDrepgfI) doesn't return anything specific worth noting to an amateur like me. Finally, [MO is empty in this regard too](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=Irrational+"packing") (but that's without looking into the minutiae of the posts that show up).

### The Question:

> Is it possible to pack $\Bbb R^n$ for some/each $n$, with copies of a regular shape and no gaps, where each copy is of a distinct, positive irrational defining length?

### Thoughts:

I'm guessing the answer is "no". Why? I don't know: pure speculation. It just seems typical of the behaviour of irrational numbers.

Having said that, though, it's just occurred to me that $\Bbb R$ can be packed with line segments, each of a distinct, (positive) irrational length. This seems obvious. List the line segments (assuming countably infinitely many is sufficient); spiral out from zero and leave no gaps.

I'm reminded of [squared squares](https://youtu.be/NoRjwZomUK0) for when $n=2$. They give me confidence that the $n=2$ case is possible. Multiply a squared square by an irrational number. Build a bigger squared square from it by keeping the ratios between the square side lengths the same as the original squared square. Carry on *ad infinitum*.

Please help :)

Comment: Getting the lengths irrational doesn't feel like a challenge at all if you use an absolute scale (as opposed to, say, requiring the *ratios* of the sizes to be irrational). After all, I would guess that "regular shape" implies that there will be only countably infinitely many tiles. A cardinality argument then tells that you can scale the whole thing to consist of irrational sized tiles only.

Comment: One of the 110x110 made out of 22 smaller squares uses a 1x1 tile. So you can use that squared square as the smallest unit, and blow up the rest by a factor of 110. Rinse, repeat. Should give you the whole plane covered by distinct sized squares , no?

Comment: But, what exactly you require from a shape to call it regular?